# Adding Latest JQuery to my MVC 4 app

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

First of all, this is my 1st MVC 4 app and I have small knowledge about it.

I am trying to add JQuery and JQueryUI latest version to the ready made MVC 4 app.

I have downloaded the necessary files and put the js files under "\Scripts" directory and css files under "\Content" directory.

The name of the JQueryUI js file is "jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"

I changed the codes in BundleConfig.cs as the following:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.custom.min.js"));
```

And in my _Layout.cshtml file, head section, I added the following code:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

But in the html file, the jquery files are not there.  It renders as the following:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

It doesn't render JQueryUI js files.  It renders the JQueryUI css file.  I have double check the location/path of the file and they are under the same directory.  I cleaned the project and re-built it again.  But they are not rendered yet.

Could you please help me how I could include them on the page?  Thanks.

Comment: What's actual name of the .js file in the `~/Scripts` folder?

Comment: The name of the JQueryUI js file is "jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might b working in debug mode,so it ignores min files. Renaming your js file to avoid 'min' suffix would be the easy fix.

check [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) for more details

Answer (score 1):

IN my Bundle config I have added in bootstrap etc.., but this is what mine looks like with jquery by itself

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~bundles/jquery").Include(
      "~/scripts/lib/jquery-{version}.js"
 ));
```

and then output is

```
 <script src="/Scripts/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

now MY _layout file contains these lines

```
@RenderSection("breakout", required: false)
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/site")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

I didn't get a chance to throw in jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js , I'll try to get back to you on that,   the .min might cause it to revert from debug,  delete the 1.9.1 from your directory, try that.